# Netbeans ribbon disabled at startup

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

When I open the Netbeans environment, the ribbon and most of the associated commands (run, build, compile, etc.) are disabled until I click on a source file tab in the editor window. This makes no sense to me. Is there an option I have inadvertently changed to display this inconvenient behavior?

Do not confuse this with freezing at startup. The environment works; I just have to click on a source file before, say pressing F6.

Product Version   = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)
Operating System  = Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64
Java; VM; Vendor  = 1.8.0_131; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11; Oracle Corporation
Runtime           = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11

The warnings in the log don't mean anything to me and so I'm reciting them here.

The following WARNINGs appear in the log for org.netbeans.core.modules:
the modules [org.netbeans.modules.form.nb] use org.jdesktop.layout which is deprecated: Use javax.swing.GroupLayout instead. (In form editor: select Form ... in Inspector; change Layout Generation Style to Standard Java 6 code.)
the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
the modules [org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant, org.netbeans.modules.java.hints, org.netbeans.modules.maven.hints] use org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.legacy.spi which is deprecated: Use Java Hints SPI (org.netbeans.spi.java.hints) instead.

The following WARNING appears in the log for org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager:
use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.nativeexecution.support.hostinfo.impl.HostInfoFactory.getNBKey(HostInfoFactory.java:417)

There is also a warning for org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge:
Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@479ddf02[MultiFileObject@4311b053[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]

Everything else looks informational and innocuous.

Comment: Update your post (and its tags) with the version of NetBeans you are using. Also, check your log for possibly relevant errors (**View -> IDE Log**).

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is working as designed, and its behavior is logical (or at least that is the intention). See the explanation on the **Start Page** for NetBeans:

> **NetBeans turns on functionality as you use it**. Start creating and
>   opening projects and the IDE will just activate the features you
>   need...

[image: StartPage]

For example, when you first start NetBeans:

- There is no active project so the **Run** button is disabled. (If it was enabled, how would NetBeans know what to run?)
- There is nothing to save so the **Save All** button is disabled.  (If it was enabled, what could you possibly save?)
- Conversely, the **New Project** and **Open Project** buttons are enabled, since it is meaningful to open an existing project, or create a new project, as soon as NetBeans is started.

If you now open an HTML file the **Run** button becomes enabled, but the **Save All** button remains disabled unless the file is edited.

Note that it is not just the buttons that are disabled; their corresponding menu entries are as well.

Comment: Netbeans doesn't open to the Start Page.  It opens to the last project I worked on so if the Run button were enabled, the project to run is obvious.  I'd show a screen shot but the environment won't let me paste it.

Comment: I uncheck the box in the upper right of the startup screen so it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: @DRF OK. Then when NetBeans starts things should resume from where they were left when NetBeans was last closed. For example, if you were on the **Services** panel, and restarted NetBeans then after restarting that panel should have focus, and the **Run** button will be disabled. But if were editing a file and restarted then that file tab should have focus with the cursor positioned where it was when NetBeans was closed, and the **Run** button should be enabled. But the **Open Project** and **New Project** buttons should always be enabled. Do you not get that behavior?

Comment: I just now had my project open. I made a change to the source file showing in the editor and exited Netbeans. I was offered a chance to save the file and I said yes. Netbeans exited. I restarted Netbeans. The file I changed is showing in the editor window and the cursor is blinking at the point I made the change. I can move the cursor with the keyboard. The ribbon is greyed out and neither Run-Run Project nor F6 function. They did not function until I clicked on a different source file tab in the editor. It's not a big deal but maybe it can go on a list somewhere?